# Understanding WCF Client to Server

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I'm having difficulty fully grasping a particular function of Windows Communication Foundation.  I've read tutorial after tutorial, book after book.  So the entire conceptual nature I feel confident on.

Except for one part; this is the part that is almost like magic.  Which actually made the learning slightly difficult.

I'll use the most common example on the web.

I'll start with the `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{

    // Declerations:
    private Guid id;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string emailAddress;

    [DataMembers]
    public Guid Id
    {
       get { return id; }
       set { id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName
    {
         get { return firstName; }
         set { firstName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName
    {
         get { return lastName; }
         set { lastName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmailAddress
    {
         get { return emailAddress; }
         set { emailAddress = value; }
    }

}
```

Now I've created an object; that I'd like to be exposed to my Client.

So I then create my `ServiceContract`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICustomer
{

     [OperationContract]
     Customer AddCustomer(Customer info);

}
```

So this where I keep confusing myself; lets say you have a Client-Side Application.  You've consumed the service.  You have three textboxes in a separate Assembly / Namespace.  The Client puts in the criteria:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address

If you set those text boxes to the date; they will transfer over in Metadata.  But on the server; how can I pull that information variable out?  Do I just reference the `private Guid and private string variables`?

I saw a tutorial on how to add it to a database; but I don't fully comprehend what WCF is actually doing.  Which is similar to what I'd like. I'd like to get the Client interface input and write it to a database and a separate log file.

I could just follow the tutorial; but I want to know how the Customer object data and it's variables are being assembled for use on the server.

Any assistance would be amazing, some clarification.

Sorry if my question is stupid; I'm not trying to start a debate.  Just want to understand how to pull those variables and use them on the server.

Thanks in advance.  If I didn't format the question correctly please let me know.  I'd really like to understand what it is conceptually doing.

*Update:*
My true intention is to understand how the Client interface references that object; so when the call is made the server has a valid object that isn't null.

Client types in text box ---> Proxy Sends ---> De-serialized ---> Service ---> Serializes ---> Makes Property available for usage.

Comment: I'm kinda lost at "If you set those text boxes to the date; they will transfer over in Metadata" - Are you asking how serialization works?

Comment: Well, if the user actually fills out those fields.  How do you retrieve those values; or get those variables.  I vaguely understand the Serialization and Deserialization but in all the examples they just callback the variable; how do you manipulate that users variable?  The serialization just magically appears when coding to that interface that you now have just a data contract variable to use?  Does that make sense?  If not I'll ponder and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: A lot of platforms use data binding to make this work.  You bind a textbox to a field in your object, then when the user changes the value, the data bound field in your object is updated.  You can then send the updated object back to your server to save it.  FYI, the proxy objects that Visual Studio creates from web service references natively support data binding operations.

Comment: So I understand; the Client Application which is located across the internet is set to be bound in the implementation of the consumption.  So from there the implementation automatically deserializes and sets the value for those properties.  So other Assemblies linked to your Service Layer can simply use the Property?  If I understood that makes sense; so all the Server has to do is pull the Property Value?

Comment: Somewhat.  When you reference your service on the client, it will construct proxy objects for the types that service exposes (such as `Customer`).  Your UI will be data bound to those proxy objects, which must be compatible (on a serialization level) with those types on the server.  In other words, your client will also have a `Customer` type with all the same properties.

Comment: That Mike was the click! So essentially in the Consumption and you create the Proxy to physically interface with the service.  That Proxy object is bound; so as the user makes a change the Proxy Channel will automatically transmit the data.  So you'll be able to use that Property object to write to a database, textfile, or do whatever.  Did I understand that correctly; I feel like I did.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you understand correctly.  I think things will become more clear when you get some code working..

Comment: Yeah that could be; all these examples are so impractical that it makes it difficult to fully grasp.  The books leave it open to interpretation which can be difficult if your just learning.  Could you submit an answer; I'd love to submit it since you did answer it. I appreciate the response.  You helped me understand it; now to come up and get an example rolling to grasp it slightly better.

Comment: See [Basics: How Web Services Work](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/basics-how-web-services-work/)

Comment: Thanks John, that is a nice information there. I'll have to really look at it closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual *types*, such as your `Customer` class are not really transmitted across the wire.  However, the public information within those types is sent across through a process called serialization.  Serialization allows a type to be represented in a way that allows it to be transmitted over a network.  This is often expressed using a format such as SOAP, JSON or XML.  WCF even allows you to control exactly how objects are serialized, allowing you to write your own formatter if you want.  Basically, when `AddCustomer` is called, WCF is constructing a `Customer` object on the server, serializing it, and sending those bits across the wire.

Now, on the client you would have a matching `Customer` object called a proxy.  It might look something like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, a scaled down version with just the data members of the server version, with no code or logic.  On the client, the serialized representation of `Customer` is deserialized back into an instance of this local proxy class, where it can be used for various client purposes, including being bound to local UI elements.

Web services can expose this type information using [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) (which is an XML format for describing a web service contract).  Visual Studio (using the wsdl.exe tool) can automatically write these proxy classes for you, which makes everything just work magically.

Comment: I like the addition of "which makes everything just work magically."  It is quite true; that magic created this post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may be this is what you are looking for 
[Data Transfer and Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730035.aspx)

In particular you can check [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731072.aspx)

You can check this article too : [Serialization in Windows Communication Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30279/Serialization-in-Windows-Communication-Foundation)